# Design-time Coding

Tags: vb.net, design-time

I'm a newbie in visual basic dot net. I tried to create a design in run-time. Here's my simple code.

```
    Dim frmLogin As New Form
    Dim lblUserName, lblPassword As New Label
    Dim txtUserName, txtPassword As New TextBox
    Dim btnContinue, btnCancel As New Button

    'set frmLogin properties
    frmLogin.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    frmLogin.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    frmLogin.BackColor = Color.LightGray
    frmLogin.Size = New Size(400, 200)

    'set lblUserName properties
    lblUserName.Text = "User Name: "
    lblUserName.Font = New Font("Calibri", 12, FontStyle.Regular)
    lblUserName.Location = New Point(20, 30)

    'set lblPassword properties
    lblPassword.Text = "Password: "
    lblPassword.Font = New Font("Calibri", 12, FontStyle.Regular)
    lblPassword.Location = New Point(20, 70)

    'set txtUserName properties
    txtUserName.Font = New Font("Calibri", 12, FontStyle.Regular)
    txtUserName.Location = New Point(120, 20)
    txtUserName.Size = New Size(250, 20)

    txtPassword.Font = New Font("Calibri", 12, FontStyle.Regular)
    txtPassword.Location = New Point(120, 60)
    txtPassword.Size = New Size(250, 20)
    txtPassword.PasswordChar = "*"

    btnCancel.Text = "Cancel"
    btnCancel.Location = New Point(270, 120)
    btnCancel.Size = New Size(100, 28)
    btnCancel.BackColor = Color.White
    btnCancel.Font = New Font("Calibri", 12, FontStyle.Regular)

    frmLogin.Controls.Add(lblPassword)
    frmLogin.Controls.Add(lblUserName)
    frmLogin.Controls.Add(txtUserName)
    frmLogin.Controls.Add(txtPassword)
    frmLogin.Controls.Add(btnCancel)
    frmLogin.ShowDialog()
```

How could I start creating a code here? I'd like to start in btnCancel, how could I insert this code in btnCancel

```
dim myAns as string = msgbox("This will exit the program. Are you sure?")
if ans = vbyes then application.exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add an event handler to the controls:

```
'register the event handler after initializing of the control
AddHandler btnCancel.Click, AddressOf CancelClick


'create a method with same signature as the delegate of the event
Private Sub CancelClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
   'do your stuff here
End Sub
```

Comment: what if i make a Code (for run-time design) inside another button? How can I insert the code for exit inside the Cancel Button.

Comment: ...and there's an error


Method 'Public Sub CancelClick(sender As Object, e As system.Windows.Forms.MoseEventArgs)'does not have the same signature as delegate 'Delegate Sub EventHandler(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)'.

Comment: sorry its EventArgs and not MouseEventArgs --> see edit. please ask your other question again, i dont understand what you mean.